Solving boundary layer equations using matrix
I am trying to formulate a solver for a coupled system of ODEs.
The equations are as follows.

So my current understanding is, this can be formulated somewhat similar to this

Now I can understand this would result in a single diagonal matrix with blocks as shown above laid out in the diagonal which upon solving results in dU/dx and I can integrate it to get the solution.
But in the formulation I am referring to, the matrix is built as below.

My question is what could this highlighted submatrix correspond to ?
Also with this formulation can I get the solution directly without integrating delta ?

This solution method uses a Newton-Raphson iteration, for fast convergence on non-linear systems. A similar application, that is reasonably ok to follow along is in Michael Giles' phd thesis ( https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/15250?show=full ).
First, we identify the variables. In this case, a suitable set of variables would be: theta, delta*, ni and Ct. This is the same varibales Drela uses in XFoil and Mises, which I believe is where you got these equations from.
To solve the system, we have to start with an initial "guess", the most basic would be to have "ni(eps)=0", "theta(eps)=0.01eps", "delta(eps)=2.2theta(x)" and Ct you can initialize with the Ct_equilibrium equation (eq 6.39 in Drela's phd thesis https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/104732?show=full ).
This initialization is very flawed, and a slightly more complicated, but still simple initialization would be to use a "marching integral" and Thwaytes, to calculate your theta and delta vectors, use ( https://www.aerodynamics4students.com/subsonic-aerofoil-and-wing-theory/2d-boundary-layer-modelling.php ) as a reference, but take into account that due to Goldstein's singularity, you will have to clamp your H, to prevent nonsensical solutions. A max value of 2-5 would be appropriate.
Once you have your intial guess, you can now compute the matrix system for this iteration. For each cell (a location with a left and a right node, where variables are named theta1 and theta2, delta1 and delta2 etc), you add a new line to your matrix. So we have 4 variable vectors (theta, delta*, ni, Ct). We have a few vectors of prescribed properties (e.g "ue", "eps"). We have 4 total equations.
Lets say our space gets discretized in 10 nodes. That gives us 9 (10-1) cells, between each node. If we count our system, we will have 104 variables, and 94 equations. We are missing 4 equations, which we complete by creating our Boundary Conditions, at epsilon=0, we have theta=0, epsilon=0, ni=0, Ct=0. Now we just need to assemble the system.
The RHS vector is simple to calculate, we iterate through each of our cells, and for each cell, we take theta1, theta2, delta1, delta2 (etc), replace them on each of the 4 equations you provided, and the resulting value is placed at this line of the RHS. so we can easily calculate 9*4 lines of the RHS, the remaining 4 values of the RHS are for the BC equations.
Then for the matrix, we have to do the hard part, which is to derive each of your non-linear equations, in function of each of our variables. This is extremely complicated to do analytically in one go. That is why the way it is usually approached is through "forward tracking", such as XFoil does it. If you are using Python, you can actually do this automatically with Pytorch, using "torch.functional.jacobian" and it will assemble the whole matrix for you if you just compute the RHS.
This forward tracking comes down to the following, method:
Lets use your Ramp equation as an example, since it is the simplest. First we decompose into "Ramp=A-B+C" where "A=ni2", "B=ni1" and "C=dnide * dEps".
Computing the derivatives of the equations is done as we compute each term.
"d(Ramp) / dv = (dA/dv - dB/dv + dC/dv)"
dA/dtheta1 = dA/dtheta2 = dA/ddelta1 = dA/ddelta2 = 0
dA/dni1 = 0
dA/dni2 = 1
dB/dtheta1 = dB/dtheta2 = dB/ddelta1 = dB/ddelta2 = 0
dB/dni1 = 0
dB/dni2 = 1
To finish the derivation of the equation, we just need the derivatives of "C". This is a bit more complicated due to how "dni/de" is calculated. So you have to find your equation for dni/de, and step by step, decompose it and calculate the derivatives of the equation to each of the 8 (theta1, theta2, delta1, delta2, Ct1, Ct2, ni1, ni2) variables on this cell.

MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference

Hi Diogo, Thanks heaps for the detailed answer. My question was more towards the structure of the matrix. I believe the reason for di-diagonal matrix is, because ln(a/b) can be represented as ln(a) - ln(b) so I think  it make sense to discretize equations in to two consecutive ones. Assuming the wall transpiration being used any idea how dFij/dmj being calculated here ? My question is more towards the fact that dmj is calculated by both d* and Ue and I believe it has to be taken into account directly into boundary layer equations to avoid the singularity even in the two equation method.

Also lets assume reasonably close solution is already at hand. If my understanding is correct given a initial state variable, the solution procedure goes as solve the matrix-> feed the new state variable to create a new matrix and solve it again -> iterate. Not marching through the nodes as in an initial value problem -- please correct me if Im wrong

4th Paragraph -- I think it should be a 4x4 system for each node isnt it to close off 3 boundary layer equations using Ue, so the state variable U at each node should be (theta, H, n|Ct , Ue) isnt it ?

5th Paragraph -- Other biggest confusion I had was this, If this was to be solved as an IVP problem, then I can use stagnation properties as my 0th node. But with the matrix these stagnation values has to somehow go to the RHS to make this a BV problem - isnt it

Regarding the iteration process:
1-Use current solution to compute RHS and derivatives, to assemble Matrix
2-Check convergence, by using some vector norm on RHS vector (in converged solution, RHS is 0). If converged, exit and use current solution.
3-Solve linear system, and use it to compute dV (deltas for each variable)
4-Update the solution by adding dV to our previous Solution
5-Go back to step1 with new solution
And like you said, this is not done "marching through nodes", all nodes are solved simultaneously in the Matrix linear system.

4th Paragraph - You are correct. Due to the equations for Ramp and Rlag switching at transition, at each "cell" you either solve for "ni" or for "Ct".
In my answer I did overlook that, and it is wrong, the way I wrote it.
XFoil does exactly as you said, and uses the variables "Ue,theta,delta*, ni/Ct" for their 4 variables per cell. Notice that using "H" or "delta*" is interchangeable, as "H=delta*/theta".

5th Paragraph: The stagnation properties do come into effect. Remember, each line of the matrix is not for "one node", but for "one cell". Each cell is between 2 nodes, so the first cell in the system is between nodes 0 and node 1. For this cell, how would you compute ln(theta2/theta1)? You cannot compute it, and instead, you use stagnation properties to "assume" this value at cell 0.
For the particular case, XFoil uses at cell 0 the following:
ln(theta1/theta0)=0
ln(H1/H0)=0
ln(Ue1/Ue0)=1

Regarding your first comment, the structure of the matrix is not exactly bi-diagonal. Actually the matrix will have up to 8 diagonals (Ue1,Ue2,theta1,theta2,delta1,delta2,ni1,ni2) at the very least. And if you use more sophisticated FiniteDifferences schemes, with higher order terms, you migh introduce non-zeros in additional diagonals, by using terms further to the left (upstream), for example. Furthermore, the exact structure of the Matrix is flexible, you can rearrange the rows/columns in any way you see fir without changing the underlying problem (as long as you change the RHS vector accordingly), the exact structure of the Matrix just helps in the numerical solving algorithms (known as pre-conditioning), but for simple/small cases it should be very flexible.
I still am not sure what is your question on the derivation part of things. Yes, you need to derive every one of the 4 equations, for every one of the 8 variables. This is fairly complicated, hence why it is done in a "forward tracking" way. Have you taken a look at the XFoil code, to wrap your head around how they do it?

Thanks Diogo. This is muchly appreciated. Yes, I had a look at the XFoil code and I realized Rmom partial U has 8 variables as you said as well. Thanks again for taking your time to reply.  Ill dig a little deeper on the subject little later to better wrap my head around it. Thanks
